# Defining userDao in AppFuse 3.5

Tags: appfuse

I am following the tutorials on http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Tutorials and I am confused on the "Register a personDao bean definition" section.

If it is necessary to register dao beans in the applicationContext.xml (or in applicationContext-dao.xml as I have seen it in an older version of an AppFuse application that I've been working with)... why is it not necessary to also register the userDao bean in the same way?

I have an alternate motive for asking this question as well...
I've been trying to port an application from an older version of the AppFuse framework (same application I mentioned above).  But when I attempt to navigate to any page other than the ones that come with the original code, I get "Page not found" errors.  Which is why I have gone back to the tutorials... I really want to get a handle on this since I am taking over someone else's code and they are no longer available for comment.

In addition, when adding the personDao to applicationContext.xml, IDEA complains "Required properties missing: 'sessionFactory'". When adding the line: , it then complains "Cannot resolve bean 'sessionFactory'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't necessary to register the userDao bean because it's already been done for you. The applicationContext-dao.xml file is included in the appfuse-hibernate (or appfuse-jpa) JAR file and it's imported into tests and in web.xml.

In it, it has the following:

```
   <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="org.appfuse.dao"/>
```

You can see the file online at http://source.appfuse.org/browse/~br=release-3.5.0/appfuse/data/hibernate/src/main/resources/applicationContext-dao.xml?r=7486012b603604294be9384475b3750865c93bb6